# Mongo commands using Batch Script

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, mongodb-query

I am trying to execute a batch script to create a collection and insert data into it. It is opening Mongo.exe but it is not executing the commands.

I have tried the following ways.

```
cd  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe
mongo.exe --eval "use MyDatabase"
mongo.exe --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'T1' , seq : 1})"
mongo.exe --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'T2' , seq : 2})"
pause
```

The above script opens Mongo.exe and does nothing other than that. I need help as I want to run every command in one connection with mongodb. So I tried:

mongo.exe mydb D:\Delta\scriptfile.js

my scriptfile.js contains:

```
print(db)
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'T1' , seq : 1})
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'T2' , seq : 2})
print(show collections)
print(db)
```

But after this it is showing that path of file D:\Delta\a.js not found.

Comment: Not a solution, but `cd` should actually read `cd /D` in order to also change the drive if necessary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your code and try:

```
cd  /D C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe mydb < D:\Delta\scriptfile.js
```

with your scriptfile.js as same:

```
print(db)
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'T1' , seq : 1})
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'T2' , seq : 2})
print(show collections)
print(db)
```